# How to avoid join using GORM Where query

Tags: join, grails, grails-orm, where-clause

I'm using Grails 2.5.4 at the moment and having an issue with the new preferred *where* closure.

Given that there are two tables where the relationship is ImportBatchRecord belongsTo ImportBatch. When trying to find ImportBatchRecord belonging to the importBatch.id == value to update the ImportBatchRecord, the query is causing a JOIN even though I have the ID of the ImportBatch. This results in the error *Joins cannot be used in a DELETE or UPDATE operation*.

The following is the *where* command for updating the ImportBatchRecord associated with the ImportBatch:

```
Integer updated = ImportBatchRecord.where {
    importBatch.id == 5
}.updateAll( status: 'PROCESSED')
```

When using HQL with the equivalent syntax it works fine.

Does anyone know if there is away for the where clause to avoid doing an unnecessary join since the query already has the ID of the reference?

TIA,

John

Answer (score -1):

try

```
Integer updated = ImportBatchRecord.where {
    importBatchId == 5
}.updateAll( status: 'PROCESSED')
```

Comment: Thanks Elixir for the suggestion however trying importBatchId results in the following error message.

    Cannot query on property "importBatchId" - no such property on class ImportBatchRecord exists

I'm guessing I'll have to switch to using HQL instead...